# Identify physical switch port a packet is coming from?

Tags: networking, security, switch

Given a network structure like this:

```
client 1 \
.         \
.          switch -- firewall
.         / 
client n /
```

(in words: all clients connected to one switch and the switch connected to the firewall)

Is it possible (on the firewall) to identify the physical port on the switch that a client used?

Background: There's some simple MAC authentification for the clients, there can only be 1 person responsible for what happens an a switch port (because there is just one RJ45 connector per room and 1 person who owns the room). However, it would be possible to fake the MAC address, then I wouldn't know from which room the data is coming, however I need to know this for sure in case of abuses. Is this possible without vlans? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can know this by implementing [port security](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/security/lock-down-cisco-switch-port-security/320) on your switch. One requirement is that you have a managed switch. Only one MAC address will be allowed on each switch port.

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect and also supported on the HP switch I am using (up to 8 MAC addresses per port)